# Windows authentication vs Android browsers in Windows Server 2008 r2 IIS7

Tags: android, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication

I have a company website which uses Windows Authentication.
The site runs on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.

When we try to access it from mobile, we get mixed results - some browsers do succeed to login, some do not even show the login window, and some do show the login window but when I enter the credentials they just show the window once more endlessly.

The breakdown of the options is like that:

```
HTC One              Android 4.22     Native Browser    SUCCESS 
Motorola Xoom 1      Andorid 4.0.4    Native Browser    repetitive login
Motorola Xoom 1      Andorid 4.0.4    Firefox           repetitive login
Motorola Razr M      Android 2.3.6    Firefox           repetitive login
Morotola Droid Pro   Android 2.3.4    Native Browser    error 401, no login screen
Morotola Droid Pro   Android 2.3.4    Firefox           SUCCESS (surprisingly...)
Samsung S I mini     someting old     Native Browser    error 401, no login screen
Samsung S I mini     someting old     Firefox           repetitive login
```

I've seen posts saying FIrefox would fix the NTLM login issue on Androids < 4.0, but I see it's not the case on the majority of Androids and also that there is a problem also on Android 4.0.4.

On iOS and WP8 the login succeeds.

My questions are:

- Why is it so?
- What can be done to use Windows Authentication reliably on mobile?

Thanks.